# Why can't mount read files in "/etc/fstab.d/"?

Tags: mount, fstab

I'm trying to setup an automatically mounted volume, and noticed that there is now an `/etc/fstab.d/` on my server. I created a new file in the directory with the following contents:

```
# backupstore: large volume
/dev/mapper/bagend-backupstore  /mnt/backupstore        ext4    auto,relatime,users,sync        0       0
```

But when I run `mount -a` the volume is not mounted. Also, when I run `mount /mnt/backupstore` or `/dev/mapper/bagend-backupstore` I get told that the system couldn't find the entry in fstab (and to pre-empt: yes, the device and mount-point are correct - I can easily mount this with `mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/bagend-backupstore /mnt/backupstore`)

When I delete the file from `/etc/fstab.d/` and put the entry into the main `/etc/fstab` file, I have no problems mounting the volume.

So, can the mount command be made to check for entries in `/etc/fstab.d/` and if yes, what do I do to make it happen?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- `/bin/mount` **cannot read** `/etc/fstab.d` yet, only the library (`libmount`) can.
- This is a [known "wishlist" bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=663623) in *util-linux*, the package which provides `mount`
- The feature has been added in the latest *util-linux* 2.21 (the [release notes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.21/v2.21-ReleaseNotes) say "Use filter arg of scandir* to pickup /etc/fstab.d/*.fstab files")
- Since even Debian Unstable (Sid) is on version 2.20-x of *util-linux*, I doubt we'll see 2.21 in Ubuntu until 13.04
- If you need it sooner, you can either compile 2.21 from the [kernel.org source](http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.21/), but I'd recommend you wait until it at least makes its way into Debian (*util-linux* provides a number of other critical system utilities/libraries as well)

Comment: As an update, Ubuntu 13.04 is still using version 2.20.1 of util-linux.

Comment: As an update Ubuntu 14.04 is still using version 2.20.1 of util-linux

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 has util-linux 2.25.  However I don't think Ubuntu's **mountall** supports /etc/fstab.d, so don't expect these to be mounted automatically on boot.

Comment: What's the status on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: As @karel-zak mentions in [their answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/169995/14601), The support for `/etc/fstab.d` was added to `mount` and then reverted. Support won't be added to `mount`.

Answer (score 13):

The `/etc/fstab.d` support has been reverted from mount(8) after upstream [discussion](http://marc.info/?l=util-linux-ng&m=132740311801201&w=2). The mount tab directories are supported by libmount only. It's not planned to support `fstab.d` in mount(8) by default.

The problem is that `/etc/fstab` is de facto standard used on many places (libc, systemd, UI programs, ..) and it's unreal wish that all the places can be changed to support `fstab.d`.

Anyway, you can use a *new* mount(8) from util-linux >= 2.21 and a new option `--fstab <path>` to specify alternative mount table, this option also supports directories. It means you have to explicitly specify the directory -- mount(8) will not read it by default. See [mount(8) man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/mount.8.html) for more details.

Comment: libmount might have superseded getfsent and made the exact files an implementation detail.  Or getfsent might have been updated.  Oh well, there's always Augeas.