# Build mount points from multiple files

Tags: mount, fstab, automount, nfs, automation

I was wondering if anyone has seen a way of specifying mount points in multiple files?

My scenario is as follows: I am trying to automate desktop provisioning and setup, using a combination of Cobbler and Ansible. I need to add my NFS mounts to every new desktop, but since the `/etc/fstab` file is unique to each PC (UUID's and all that), I can't easily distribute a new copy of `/etc/fstab` to every PC with the required mount points.

What I am looking for is perhaps some way to 'include' another file from `fstab` or perhaps some equivalent to the usual `run-parts`-based configuration method (i.e. an `/etc/fstab.d/`).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Only thing I have found is Q&A at (General) [Can I include another file in fstab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62819/can-i-include-another-file-in-fstab) and (Ubuntu) [Why can't mount read files in “/etc/fstab.d/”?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168290/why-cant-mount-read-files-in-etc-fstab-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue you had with the same scripts.

When Ansible gathers facts it makes a bunch of variables available for you.

You can find your root UUID on the variable ansible_cmdline.root.

Here's my mount configuration:

```
mount_devices:
  - name: /
    src: "{{ ansible_cmdline.root }}"
    fstype: ext4
    opts: defaults,discard
    state: mounted
    dump: 0
    passno: 0

  - name: /etc/network/interfaces.dynamic.d
    src: none
    fstype: tmpfs
    opts: nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=64K
    state: mounted
    dump: 0
    passno: 0

  - name: /mnt
    src: /dev/disk/azure/resource-part1
    fstype: auto
    opts: defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig
    state: mounted
    dump: 0
    passno: 2

  - name: /shared
    src: no
    fstype: cifs
    opts: vers=2.1,username=no,password=xyz
    state: mounted
    dump: 0
    passno: 2
```